# How to calculate magnetic field strength through multiple media?

Tags: electromagnetism, integration

I'm writing a simulator, and I've found I need greater accuracy than can be afforded by the typical magnetic field equation like given [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html). So I'm converting my script to integrate over the wire's length, like in [this](https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/osuniversityphysics2/chapter/magnetic-field-due-to-a-thin-straight-wire/) derivation. But I'm still left without a good estimate of the magnetic field strength at a point, because even the equation listed there assumes a constant permeability.

I've heard people argue that the only permeability that matters is the lowest one because that will dominate i.e. if you've got an inch of steal and an inch of air, just use the permeability of air, kind of like you just use the resistance in a resistor and ignore the wire. If this is the case, do I just calculate as though the wire were 1 inch away in air rather than 2 inches in steal then air?

And supposing I just use the distance from the steal, as I integrate across each section, do I just take the distance from the point to the steal in line with the dx, or does the magnetic field take the "path of least resistance" so to speak, traveling along the steal until it jumps out 1 inch across the air gap?